# How to iterate over all videos stored in camera roll?

Tags: iphone, ios, video, avfoundation

Is there a way to iterate over all videos stored in camera roll? I want to list them in a table view, and when you tap one you see the metadata.

Where would I start?

Comment: [try with this link in this you will ge][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508178/how-do-i-get-only-the-videos-using-alassetslibrary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to list them in a table view, it sounds like you don't want to use Apple's UIImagePickerController.

In that case, you need to go down to the lower-level API's.

For example, you can use [ALAssetsLibrary's `[enumerateGroupsWithTypes: usingBlock: failureBlock:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ALAssetsLibrary/enumerateGroupsWithTypes:usingBlock:failureBlock:) to get at all of your ALAsset objects in your camera roll.  As your app looks at each ALAsset, you need to make certain the ALAsset url is a video ([and this related question shows you how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17191701/how-to-know-whether-alasset-url-contains-video-or-image)).

Comment: Is it also possible to modify an existing photo or video?

Comment: It may be, but only from your own app ([see this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768257/replace-alasset-object-in-ios-alassetslibrary)).

Comment: Yes, only from the app that created the video, it seems.

Comment: I posted example code that does this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23727617/1161906).